# C# - load xaml file at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, runtime

I have a WPF application in C#.

I have a `MainWindow` class which inherits from a `System.Windows.Window` class.

Next I have an xaml file on my disk which I want to load at runtime:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="I want to load this xaml file">
</Window>
```

How can I load that xaml file at runtime? In other words, I want my MainWindow class to use exactly the mentioned xaml file, so I do **not** want to use the method `AddChild` of the MainWindow because it adds a child to the window, but I want to **replace** also that `Window` parameter. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try Xaml Reader.

See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910814/loading-xaml-at-runtime

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I have already seen that page before - everything there is greatly described, just according to that post, I **cannot replace** the `Window` parameter to one from the xaml file on disk - I can **just add new child** to it.

Comment: What do you mean with "Window Parameter"? The top <Window> tag *is* a description of the class that becomes an instance of Window after xaml is processed. If you want to replace the instance of MainWindow then the question is who holds this instance, that is where is the variable to change? You can then change this variable with the result from XamlReader.

Comment: Peter, in your very own interest, if you expect people to make efforts to assist you in the future, you should read, comment and vote for the suggested answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WPF application has by default, in the VS template, a StartupUri parameter:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication2.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
</Application>
```

The WPF framework will use this uri to **instantiate** a window class using XamlReader and **show it**. In your case - remove this StartUpUri from App.xaml and instantiate the class manually, so you can then hide it when you load your other window from xaml.

Now add this code to App.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class App : Application
 {
    Window mainWindow; // the instance of your main window

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
 }
```

To "replace" this  Window with another window you:

- hide this window using mainWindow.Hide();
- read your personal.xaml with XamlReader which gives you the Window instance for the loaded Xaml.
- assign it to mainWindow (if you want) and call Show() to display it.

Whether you want the instance of your apps "main window" hold a member of the App instance or not is certainly your choice.

In summary, the whole trick is:

- hide the main window
- load your window instance
- show your window instance

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. The key was to replace the `Window` instance with a new one, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
- No, you cannot **replace** the `Window` from inside the `Window`. There is nothing you have access to inside a `Window`-derived object that says "hey, replace *everything* with this other window"

Longer answer:
- You can, however, do something silly like this:

```
private void ChangeXaml()
{
    var reader = new StringReader(xamlToReplaceStuffWith);
    var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader);
    var newWindow = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as Window;    
    newWindow.Show();
    foreach(var prop in typeof(Window).GetProperties())
    {
        if(prop.CanWrite)
        {
            try 
            {
                // A bunch of these will fail. a bunch.
                Console.WriteLine("Setting prop:{0}", prop.Name);
                prop.SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(newWindow, null), null);
            } catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
    newWindow.Close();
    this.InvalidateVisual();
}
```