# How to create a control and define it's data bindings at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

The end result that I'm imagining is that I have an XML file that defines the layout of certain parts of the UI.  At execution, (1) I read the XML file in and (2) build out the controls and assign their DataContexts to the associated ViewModels.  Can anyone share any examples of part (2) that they've come across or perhaps show one?

Comment: I am not sure that [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532772/c-sharp-load-xaml-file-at-runtime) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021677/loading-xaml-at-runtime-using-the-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf) are exact duplicates to your question, but nonetheless you may want to take a look.

Comment: google for datatemplates and datatemplateselector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isnt it much easier to define DateTemplates for your viewmodels.

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyViewmodel}" >
  <view:MyViewmodelView/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

then create your Viewmodels "dynamic" and assign the Viewmodels to a ContentControl? then WPF handle your how your Viewmodel is to render.

```
  <ContentControl Content="{Binding MyWorkspace}"/>
```

MainViewmodel

```
   public object MyWorkspace {get;set;}

   this.MyWorkspace = new MyViewmodel();
```