# Is there an online XAML tester?

Tags: c#, xaml, azure-devops

I have a bit of [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml) I want to test. Is there a "XAML-fiddle" type rendering application available *totally online*?

And yes, I Googled it. That's always my first reaction (for everything all the time).

Comment: Think about it for a second. How would a xaml rendering engine work "totally online"? The entire WPF stack is built on DirectX. To build a xaml rendering engine online, you would have to rebuild from scratch the entire WPF stack down to WebGL, which would be insane.

Comment: @Aron I wouldn't be against seeing a supported version of "*No...that would be insane*" as an answer.

Comment: @LCIII It would be an ENTIRE rewrite of the WPF stack. There aren't many companies that have that kind of resources. Not to mention it would be impossible to produce a bug for bug implementation. Finally, it would be unable to use compiled WPF controls that you reference. Ultimately, yes, it would be a lot of work for a product that has almost zero commercial viability.

Comment: You could definitely render XAML to an image and return that to view online - that wouldn't be "totally insane". :P

Comment: Yes, all you need to do is to accept XAML in a web-request and render it at runtime: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910814/loading-xaml-at-runtime

Comment: @Aron Your reply is not helpful. Even though you think it is impossible, there are many people who are a lot more capable than you. If you do not have any idea how to solve something it is better to just say nothing rather than attack the question.

Comment: @sinsro, thank you for necromancing this question. Notice that this question is close to 10 years old. A LOT has changed since then, including and not limited to Microsoft Open Sourcing WPF, WebAsm and WebGPU. Technically, rewriting WPF in the browser stack IS possible now (how would you support user defined controls with (C#) behaviors). In fact, I have an open issue in the WPF repo asking for this https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3727. However it is unlikely to happen, since WPF is now a "Community Run Project".

Comment: @sinsro Notice however, that in the intervening years, how many technologies and changes had to come about before it could even be technically possible. Open source WPF, WebAsm, CLR on WebAsm, WebGPU, VXDK. Without these techs, it would simply be impossible for any XAML tester to work with any 3rd party controls, which would very much defeat the point.

Answer (score 4):

XAML Spy also allows to fiddle with XAML.

http://xamlspy.com/

Comment: XAML Spy has been retired and is no longer available for purchase.

Answer (score 3):

XamlPad isn't online but it's a very small application that lets you fiddle with Xaml. It sounds like it's exactly what you want:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398(v=vs.90).aspx